# If / else condition fails with JS innerHTML value setting with AJAX consult

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with If condition when I want to check a value setting from and AJAX consult.

I made a simple page to show the problem:

Main page: https://testdomain3.000webhostapp.com/Test.php

AJAX response: https://testdomain3.000webhostapp.com/Response.php

With the "Yes" and "No" buttons you set the innerHTML value of Span "txtHint4" to "Yes" or "No" respectively.

If click "Check" button, Span "txtHint6" shows value "Ok" if "txtHint4"=Yes or "Ko" if "txtHint4"=No.

All of this works well setting innerHTML "txtHint4" value with the buttons like said but if I set the value with and AJAX consult (with button "Ask AJAX") the if.. then.. statement executed with "Check" button fails to verify the condition and shows "Ko" when it should show "Ok" because "txtHint4"=Yes.

Its the main code:

```
<html> 

<body>

   <div style="width:1000px; float:left"> 
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Yes" onclick="Yes()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold;padding:5px"/>
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="No" onclick="No()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold;padding:5px"/>
   </div>   

     <div style="width:1000px; float:left"> 
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Ask AJAX" onclick="Ask()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px"/>
   </div>        
     
   <div style="border: 1px solid black; width:990px;float:left; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:0px; font-size:50">
              <span id="txtHint4"></span>                        
   </div>   
     
     <div style="width:1000px; float:left; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:30px"> 
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Check" onclick="Check()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px"/>
   </div>   
     
     <div style="border: 1px solid black; width:990px;float:left; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px; font-size:50"> 
                <span id="txtHint6"></span>                      
   </div>   
     
     <div style="width:1000px; float:left"> 
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Erase" onclick="Erase()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold;padding:5px"/>
   </div>   

     
     
<script>
function Yes(){
    document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML="Yes";
;}                                                                                                                                          
</script>       

<script>
function No(){
    document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML="No";
;}                                                                                                                                          
</script>       

<script>
function Check() {
 var Text=document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML;
 if (Text=="Yes"){document.getElementById("txtHint6").innerHTML = "ok";}
 else {document.getElementById("txtHint6").innerHTML = "ko";}                               
;}
</script>

<script>
function Ask() {
                                   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML = this.responseText;}      
                                                         xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://testdomain3.000webhostapp.com/Response.php", true);   
                             xmlhttp.send();                                     
                              }
</script>

<script>
function Erase(){
    document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("txtHint6").innerHTML="";
;}                                                                                                                                          
</script>   


</body>
</html>
```

And the consult AJAX page:

```
<?php

echo "Yes";
        
;?
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `onreadystatechange` fires multiple times on different stages when the AJAX call is proceeding. You've to check the readyState and status, or use `onload` instead, and check the status only. Please consult a XMLHttpRequest guide, like the one at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.trim()](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function to make sure any **unseen spaces** are `removed` from the `responseText`.

When you add `innerHTML` its adding unseen `spaces` to your `txtHint4` text. So when checking the `if` condition just use `trim()` with you Text.

In addtion, i would also recemned using [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) as oppose to `innerHTML` since you are only adding simple `text` and and not `HTML text`

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function Yes() {
  document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML = "Yes";
}

function No() {
  document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML = "No";
}

function Erase() {
  document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("txtHint6").innerHTML = "";
}

function Check() {
  var Text = document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML;
  if (Text.trim() == "Yes") { //use trim() function
    document.getElementById("txtHint6").innerHTML = "ok";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("txtHint6").innerHTML = "ko";
  };
}

function Ask() {
  let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
  };

  req.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://testdomain3.000webhostapp.com/Response.php", true);
  req.send();
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div style="width:1000px; float:left">
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Yes" onclick="Yes()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold;padding:5px" />
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="No" onclick="No()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold;padding:5px" />
  </div>

  <div style="width:1000px; float:left">
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Ask AJAX" onclick="Ask()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px" />
  </div>

  <div style="border: 1px solid black; width:990px;float:left; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:0px; font-size:50">
    <span id="txtHint4"></span>
  </div>

  <div style="width:1000px; float:left; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:30px">
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Check" onclick="Check()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px" />
  </div>

  <div style="border: 1px solid black; width:990px;float:left; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px; font-size:50">
    <span id="txtHint6"></span>
  </div>

  <div style="width:1000px; float:left">
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Erase" onclick="Erase()" id="button" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:32px; font-weight:bold;padding:5px" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I didnt know innerHTML adds unseen spaces. Greetings.

Comment: @Ra2ven Happy to help. No problem.